# How to find the number of hours between two timestamps in Db2

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to subtract 2 timestamp to get the hours between them. I have use days_between function but it returns me an error of Invalid operation:function days_between has no timezone setup. Below is the sample table and timestamps that I want to subtract.

```
job_number     timestamp 1         timestamp 2
123456789   2020-03-16 16:59:26   2020-03-17 10:58:25
134232125   2020-03-18 08:57:05   2020-03-19 01:47:26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HOURS_BETWEEN function is the cleanest way to find the number of full hours between two timestamps in DB2

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061478.html

> The HOURS_BETWEEN function returns the number of full hours between the specified arguments.

For example

```
VALUES 
(    HOURS_BETWEEN('2020-03-17-10.58.25', '2019-03-16-16.59.26')
,    HOURS_BETWEEN('2020-03-19-01.47.26', '2019-03-18-08.57.05')
)
```

returns

```
1   |2   
----|----
8801|8800
```

Note that the value is negative if the first value is less than the second value in the function

Also note that this function does not exist in version of Db2 (for LUW) lower than 11.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function with numeric-expression is equal to `8` to represent `hour` difference :

```
SELECT job_number, TIMESTAMPDIFF(8,CHAR(timestamp2 - timestamp1)) AS ts_diff 
  FROM T
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ff9f39172101b8161f27bfba78e17c0e)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Sir, I embeded it to my code but I'm getting syntax error. Below is my code. ```drop table if exists table_4a;
create temp table table_4a as 
select job_number, DLCx_Date, AFL_Date, rework, case when rework > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end as yes_no, TIMESTAMPDIFF(8,CHAR(DLCx_Date - AFL_Date)) as Dwell_time
from(select a.job_number, a.DLCx_Date, a.AFL_Date, b.rework
from table_2a a left join table_3a b on a.job_number = b.job_number); ```

Comment: Hi @JuliusBennSabeniano , What are the data types of `DLCx_Date` and `AFL_Date` ? Are they really of timestamp type?

Comment: @JuliusBennSabeniano , What error message do you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

[TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000861.html) function has quite a specific implementation. See `Table 3. TIMESTAMPDIFF computations`.

I've set earlier year (2019) for `timestamp 1` values deliberately.

```
WITH TAB (job_number, timestamp1, timestamp2) AS
(
VALUES
  (123456789, TIMESTAMP('2019-03-16-16.59.26'), TIMESTAMP('2020-03-17-10.58.25'))
, (134232125, TIMESTAMP('2019-03-18-08.57.05'), TIMESTAMP('2020-03-19-01.47.26'))
)
SELECT job_number
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(8, CHAR(TIMESTAMP2 - TIMESTAMP1)) HOURS_TSDIFF
, ((DAYS(TIMESTAMP2) - DAYS(TIMESTAMP1)) * 86400 + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP2) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP1)) / 3600 HOURS_REAL  
FROM TAB;
```

The result is:

```
|JOB_NUMBER |HOURS_TSDIFF|HOURS_REAL |
|-----------|------------|-----------|
|123456789  |8777        |8801       |
|134232125  |8776        |8800       |
```